How do i make my code read a bunch of files that are paired by the date of their creation, and have them compared in those pairs?
First off, I am in no way great at Python, so i'm sure there are better ways to go about this, but:
I have three different codes, that currently do the following:
Code 1 and 2 take a CSV file each, remove unwanted columns etc. and convert them to XSLX files - the following code is what is done in code 1 and 2, only changing the name of the file itself (Report1 vs Report2):
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

# Read the CSV file (assuming the column is the first one)
df = pd.read_csv(f"C:/Users/User/Python/Project/Report1 -{date.today().year}-{date.today().month:02d}-{date.today().day:02d}.csv", header=None)

# Split the first column into separate columns based on spaces
max_commas = df[0].str.split(',').transform(len).max()
df[[f'name_{x}' for x in range(max_commas)]] = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)

# Drop the original unnamed column
df.drop(0, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Drop the last column (name_0 - showing time of report)
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='name_0')))]

# Save the modified DataFrame to a new XLSX file
try:
    df.to_excel(f"Report1File {date.today().year}-{date.today().month:02d}-{date.today().day:02d}.xlsx", index=None)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error saving the file: {e}")

output_path = f"C:/Users/User/Python/Project/Report1 {date.today().year}-{date.today().month:02d}-{date.today().day:02d}.xlsx"
df.to_excel(output_path, index=None)
print(f"Result saved as {output_path}")

Code 3 uses the two output Excel files from Code 1 and 2 above as input. As shown in the above, the files are named with a date suffix, for example, "Report1File 02.04.2024" and "Report2File 02.04.2024". These two files are then compared to find any differences, and tells me if any are found:
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

import Report1
import Report2

Report1
Report2

# Read the Excel files
df1 = pd.read_excel(f"Report1File {date.today().year}-{date.today().month:02d}-{date.today().day:02d}.xlsx", skiprows=[2])
df2 = pd.read_excel(f"Report2File {date.today().year}-{date.today().month:02d}-{date.today().day:02d}.xlsx", skiprows=[3])

# Compare the dataframes
differences = df1.compare(df2)

if differences.empty:
    print("None found")

else:
    print("Differences found in:")
    print(differences)

Now, I need to have the code read a bunch of files in a single folder, where the files are paired with the same date. For example:
- "Report1File 02.04.2024" and "Report2File 02.04.2024"
- "Report1File 01.04.2024" and "Report2File 01.04.2024" and so forth
I want the code to compare the paired files and tell me if there are any differences between "Report1File 02.04.2024" and "Report2File 02.04.2024", as well as between "Report1File 01.04.2024" and "Report2File 01.04.2024".
Currently stuck as to how to proceed, so i haven't a clue what to try :-)
I see that other posts might have similar questions, but unsure how to implement a solution into my code

assuming for each day there are always two files (and nothing else)
import os

files = os.listdir("the directory")
files.sort()

reports1 = files[:len(files)//2]
reports2 = files[len(files)//2:]

for file1,file2 in zip(reports1,reports2):
    ...

i would highly recommend making Report1 and Report2 a function and passing the requested filename to it though
def Report(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"C:/Users/User/Python/Project/{filename} -{date.today().year}-{date.today().month:02d}-{date.today().day:02d}.csv", header=None)
    ...

